# Failing task since return code was -1 while expected 0 - Bamboo

Tags: python, linux, bamboo

I have a simple hello world python script in the Bitbucket Repo. I have linked my Bamboo and Bitbucket with a `Default job` which has two tasks:

1. Source Code Checkout
2. Script

When I run the plan with the Script as `Inline` and type in `python hello_world.py` it works fine and prints out 'hello world' in the `logs`.

But when I run the plan with the Script as a `file` and give the file name as 'hello_world.py'. The build fails with the following in the log:

`Failing task since return code of [/var/lib/ci/xml-data/build-dir/ABCD-BAM-JOB1/hello_world.py] was -1 while expected 0`

Bamboo Running in GNU linux.

My Script

```
#! /usr/bin python
print('Hello World')
```

Script Task config:
[image]

**EDIT 1**

The interpreter has three options

1. Shell
2. windows powershell
3. /bin/sh or cmd.exe

Comment: In the script configuration pane, what other options do you have for "Interpreter"?

Comment: hi @brentertainer. I have Edited that in the question.

Comment: I am quite confused. Shell seems like the right way to go. One other thing I noticed is that in your post, you also have a space between `#!` and `/usr/bin/python`. Maybe make sure when you are trying things from my answer that you do NOT include that space. If that's not it, I am at a loss for ideas.

Comment: @brentertainer yeah I removed the space too. Okay Thanks for helping though. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. It is because of Permissions.

In case someone has the same problem of not having terminal access because you are in a corporate setup. Just Do:

1. Create a Script Task and write Inline, `chmod XXX filename`.
2. Create another Script Task and call the file there.

This should change the permissions. Note that the permissions change back once the Build is finished.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your ['shebang'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line to `#!/usr/bin/python`. Right now, your system is probably trying to execute it with `/usr/bin` which is a directory, not an executable.

Some will argue that something like `#!/usr/bin/env python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python3` is more robust. It really depends on how your system is configured.

Comment: Thanks. None of the above works! Throws the same error. My system has `/usr/bin` it says `env` is not a directory and `python` and `python2.7`is also not a directory. So that's why i used `#! /usr/bin python`. Not sure why none of these work.

Comment: Yes, your system has a `/usr/bin` which is a directory, not an executable. You have a space between `/usr/bin` and `python`. That is not correct. You should specify the full path `/usr/bin/python` where the space is replaced with a slash.

Comment: If your system does not have a `/usr/bin/python`, you _should_ be able to locate your python by executing `which python` from the command line.

Comment: Ok, `which python` gives me `/usr/bin/python`. I tried `#!/usr/bin/python` still doesn't work :(